# Finding expected probability of finding a set of points in space in a certain geometry

Tags: geometry, 3d

I'm stuck on a rather peculiar question (for lack of an advanced math background), that boils down to this: is it possible to quantify the probability of finding n points in space, in a certain configuration? Configuration here implies rotational invariance, that is, if I have coordinates of all n points, they don't move with respect to each other if they are fixed into a certain configuration.

For example, say you have 8 points defining the vertices of a cube. If you rotate the cube in 3D, the configuration I am talking of doesn't change. The coordinates however, do change. What is the probability of finding those 8 points in such a configuration, out of all possible configurations that they could possibly be in?

Comment: You'd have to define the underlying distribution of the points. Where are they allowed to be? And how are they distributed? Are they independent of one another?

Comment: Also, if say you move one of the points a tiny little bit, do you consider that to be another distinct configuration (so that there are infinitely many distinct possible configurations)? If so, then most likely the probability of one particular configuration will be zero.